# Return current month and year plus 1 month SSRS/Expression

Tags: sql, vba, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

so this returns the next month:

```
=MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", +1, CDate(Today))))
```

So if its November, this returns December. That is great. However, I need to return month - year one month ahead.

So if its November i want it to return December 2013. If its December 2013 I want it to return January 2014. Help?

Answer (score 2):

```
=Format(DateAdd("m", 1, CDate(Today)),"mmm - yyyy")
```

Read the documentation I've linked in order to learn more about the 'Format' function. Basically, this function takes in:

1. An Expression, in this case a date
2. A String, in this case "mmm - yyyy"

It then follows a set of rules, parsing the data into the given format. There are a handful of other formats that you can specify. These are explained in the documentation.

SOURCE: VBA Experience, [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx)

Comment: that returns this: 00-2013

Comment: @user1211611 try with capital "M". "MMM - yyyy"

Comment: ah there it is - for future reference, where can i actually learn this rather than copy/paste

Comment: @user1211611 I've added a brief explanation. I'd recommend glancing through the VBA documentation I linked, especially the example code. Hope this helps!